# Android Studio Internet Permission error

Tags: android, manifest

I have used the internet permission in my manifest I have placed it above the application and below the application but no matter where I put it I get a warning that it is not allowed there.  Also I did use an intent filler and that also gets a warning.  When I run my App I get a permission denied error.  Below is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jrodriguez.myrssfeed">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permissions android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelled the command, there is no "s" to permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jrodriguez.myrssfeed">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```